# How to install Edge/Chrome extension offline? Not in DevMode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

The question is not about Developer Mode "load unpacked". If the extension is loaded as unpacked then it shows additional popup on the normal browsers. Canary and Dev do not show this popup (used the extension for a while) but I have to use the build in Edge and regular Chrome.

I want to install extension from local source or from my webpage(over HTTPS).
I have the extension and can modify it (manifest, content script, etc.).
I have complete control over the local machine. I can add registries, local policies and templates (not AD joined but MS account), change folders, hosts file, etc.
I have already submited the extension to Google Web Store for review. It might  be delayed for a week or more, might fail review or both.

I asked related question [How can I skip manual tests for a private Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238020/how-can-i-skip-manual-tests-for-a-private-chrome-extension)

So is there a working guide for installing extension in offline/corporate mode?

The extension might be visible on the extension page but it should not show warnings and/or additional icons.

Somehow I do not manage to understandand and successfully follow [Alternate extension distribution methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/alternate-distribution-options) or [Deploying Connect Extensions in Closed Environments](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aspera-connect/3.11?topic=a-deploying-connect-extensions-in-closed-environments) guides.

Any help would be apriciated.

p.s. Worst case scenario is to pack a lot of files in extension package and update it in large chunks. Current extension connects to web server and uses pictures and sounds from the server. On the fly speach generation is almost ready. Can not use the common browser/OS voices.

Comment: From [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/#prereqs): *Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store*. It seems that we must upload the extensions to stores if we want to use them on Windows and Mac. So I think the first step is to upload your extension to Chrome Web Store or Microsoft Store. Then you can download the `.crx` file from the store to install it locally.

Comment: In MS Edge the option to pack extension to crx+pem is easily accessible (extensions-> enable developer mode-> pack extension). Did not find the option in Chrome but the crx file is basicly a zip file. My issue is with disabling the developer mode extensions popup. I can not find working instructions how to add the rady crx file. There should be a possibility to add the extensions in corporate mode (intranet enabled but internet disabled or heavily filtered) from fileshare. Either policies or SCCM+MSI or something similar.

Comment: But you are right. Chrome should not accept local extensions. I can use web page and if required shuffle some local PC settings (hosts, certificates, registry. Anyway it took less than a week for the extension to be reviewed and allowed for access by trusted test user group. I guess that more detailed and strict review will be performed for semi public listing (direct link or external search engine) and even more for regular Google  Web Store listing.

Comment: @YuZhou, the information that you quote is usefull but intended for end users. But there are additional options that are not intended for the usual end users. "Users can easily install items from any URL that matches an item in this list. Both the location of the *.crx file and the page where the download is started from (the referrer) must be allowed by these patterns."  is written on https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#ExtensionInstallSources  Most end users will not hear about Canary, https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/ ,registry, policy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/#prereqs): *Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store.* It seems that we must upload the extensions to stores if we want to use them on Windows and Mac. So I think the first step is to upload your extension to Chrome Web Store or Microsoft Store. Then you can download the `.crx` file from the store to install it locally.